# Why Spring Data r2dbc not detecting Transaction manager by method return type when using @Transactional annotation?

Tags: spring-transactions, spring-data-r2dbc

In my project we need to use 2 transaction managers(for JPA and R2DBC),
both of them are initialized with auto-configuration(two beans with names **transactionManager** and **connectionFactoryTransactionManager**),
documentation([link](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/data-access.html#tx-decl-explained)) says that:

> Methods returning a reactive type such as Publisher or Kotlin Flow (or a subtype of those) qualify for reactive transaction management.

But actually is not true, spring fails with exception message:
`No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.transaction.TransactionManager' available: expected single matching bean but found 2: transactionManager,connectionFactoryTransactionManager`

When I analyzed the code, the main logic detecting which tx manager to use is located in **TransactionAspectSupport.determineTransactionManager**

but unfortunately this logic not detecting tx manager by methods returning type, as it says the documentation.
Well, as a workaround I can choose which tx manager to use explicitly in "@Transactional" annotation.
This logic(auto detection of which tx manager to use depending on method return value) is not implemented yet, or I'm doing something wrong?